# Unable to see the Query output

Tags: psql

Unable to see the query output.

Command changed from the postgres=# to postgres'#.

Please guide.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtNAR.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your insert query the value `'Mango` there is a typo, the closing string literal `'` is missing. The console is waiting for that that is why you have the `'#` showing up.

Comment: Thanks.One question. What's the purpose of python scripts to create a schema or table creations for PostgreSQL databases.